# Override methods used with GroovyBeans notation

Tags: groovy

Today I stumbled with what it looked like a little Groovy magic when I found out I could get a property from a List of Maps using the GroovyBeans dot notation:

```
List list = [[a: 1, b: 2], [c: 3, d: 4]]
assert list.b == [2, null]
```

This will be great for my use case if the value returned was, in the example above, 2 only. I thought that to override the getAt method would do the trick, and in fact this works (in this example if there is more than 1 non null result it will return the first which is OK)

```
List.metaClass.getAt = { String s -> return delegate.findAll({ Map m -> m.get(s) }).get(0).get(s) }

List list = [[a: 1, b: 2], [c: 3, d: 4]]
assert list.getAt("b") == 2
```

but... if I use the dot notation the method being invoked is *not* the getAt(String)

```
List.metaClass.getAt = { String s -> return delegate.findAll({ Map m -> m.get(s) }).get(0).get(s) }

List list = [[a: 1, b: 2], [c: 3, d: 4]]
assert list.b == 2 // Assertion failed
```

I couldn't find what method is being invoked with the dot notation... Anybody have any clues?

You may wonder why I want to use the dot notation when calling the method explicitly gives me what I want, but in fact this is part of a DSL I'm writing so I can easily explain to people who are going to use it what is for instance

```
current.processDate
```

but it's hard to explain they have to do

```
current[0].processDate ?: current[1].processDate
```

or even

```
current.getAt("processDate")
```

Thanks in advance.

---

### UPDATE

I now think think it is impossible to do so. I stepped thru all  the code I could, the piece of code that actually get values for the maps in the list and accumulates those values is

```
DefaultGroovyMethods
private static List getAtIterable(Iterable coll, String property, List<Object> answer)
```

and I can't override it like this

```
DefaultGroovyMethods.metaClass.static.getAtIterable = {
    coll, property, answer ->
        def find = coll.find { it != null }
        return find
}
```

I also tried to override the very first method called in the dot notation

```
AbstractCallSite
    public Object callGetProperty(Object receiver) throws Throwable {
        return this.acceptGetProperty(receiver).getProperty(receiver);
    }
```

like this:

```
AbstractCallSite.metaClass.callGetProperty = {
    Object receiver ->
        if ( !(receiver instanceof ArrayList)){
            return delegate.callGetProperty(receiver)
        }
        return "SOMETHING"
}
```

So maybe it's time to call it quits?

Comment: `[[a: 1, b: 2], [c: 3, d: 4]].findResult { it.b }` should be an easier approach.

Comment: Or `list.b.findAll()`

Comment: @ dmahapatro, @ tim_yates, thanks for your replies but the question here is not the implementation of the overrode method but how to invoking it using the dot notation instead of the direct method call. I'm going t change the question to make that note. Cheers.

Comment: @Roland that is strange because I do am using IntelliJ. But note that the result I'm getting is [2, 0] but [2, null]. And in IntelliJ if I inspect the result in the Evaluate Expression the result I have is  a ArrayList with size = 2 and with element[0] = 2. No null element appears strangely...